# surfaceview time chart using drawline

Tags: android, time, charts, surfaceview

I am trying to draw a simple dynamic line (time chart refreshed every 0.25 seconds) in my SurfaceView

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { 
canvas.drawLine(array_of_x[i],array_of_y[i],array_of_x[i+1], array_of_y[i+1],mPaint);
}
```

However, it shows all past lines (I want to show only the current line); I tried invalidate() but it does not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
```

or whatever color you want to clear your Canvas with before drawing next line. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Sahil. Perfect answer.